# What version should I download?

Tags: system-requirements

Migrating from XP.
Dell 2400,Pentium 4, 2.66 GHz, 1.25 RAM
Use my desktop for Open Office, Firefox, Outlook ( will switch to Thunderbird), Microsoft Money.
What would be the smartest and easiest version to switch to?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

> **Lubuntu** is a free, Linux-based operating system that supports a wide
>   range of computers and hardware. It’s fast, safe and secure (Linux
>   doesn’t require virus software, for example) it’s also really easy to
>   use, and there are thousands of applications available for it.

Check this excellent article on [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/four-reasons-why-windows-xp-users-should-switch-to-lubuntu-this-april).

I'm suggesting **[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)** simply because your system is pretty old (Pentium 4) and you'll have a better user experience with Lubuntu than Ubuntu (Unity).

Answer (score 1):

You should give Lubuntu a try. Same thing but more lightweight. http://lubuntu.net/

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally I have upgraded exactly the same system as yours today to Lubuntu for a friend!
Had to add RAM from 3/4G to 1.5G and tried to put Ubuntu 13:10 on via USB. Wouldn't work although the CPU (Cel 2400Gh) and 1.5G RAM seems fine. The whole thing froze when I "Tried" Ubuntu with the Dev/root showing as full.
So added Lubuntu 13:10 via Netbootin and it worked a charm.
I had already weaned them off Thunderbird to Gmail via Chrome Browser so have to confess I cannot vouch for that. Will add Libre Office instead of Abiword which is the default word processor (so similar to Open Office).
I switched from Microsoft Money some years ago to KmyMoney on Ubuntu and again that is very similar to MS Money and will import banking files the same way.
Additionally the layout of Lubuntu is more like Windows XP than Unity on Ubuntu.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may install ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It is a linux based good operating system and does not require much memory